# Figuring out why disk-pressure taint is unremovable

Tags: kubernetes

I have a two-server kubernetes cluster in my homelab. One of the nodes keeps getting marked with the `node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure` taint.

If I run `kubectl taint nodes homelab02 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure-`
it returns

> ```
> node/homelab02 untainted
> ```

and then run
`kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TAINTS:.spec.taints --no-headers`
immediately after, the taint is back:

> ```
> homelab01    <none>
> homelab02    [map[effect:NoSchedule key:node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure timeAdded:2024-03-12T22:47:44Z]]
> ```

I've checked the disk space, and it IS decreasing, but there are 165GB free atm...

Is there a way I can figure out what is causing the taint being reapplied faster than I can type the command to remove it again?

## UPDATE

after running  `kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=homelab02`

I got this:

> ```
> LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                 OBJECT         MESSAGE
> 49s         Warning   EvictionThresholdMet   node/homelab02 Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
> ```

I ran `journalctl -u kubelet` as indicated by [this article](https://support.d2iq.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409472622868-Pods-being-evicted-Attempting-to-reclaim-ephemeral-storage), but that resulted in

> ```
> -- No entries --
> ```

Just to check that the issue is still current, I ran the commands above, untatinting and reconfirming the taint, and then the journalctl command again - the output is persistent.

### describe node output

> ```
> Name:               homelab02
> Roles:              worker
> Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
>                     beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s
>                     beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
>                     kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
>                     kubernetes.io/hostname=homelab02
>                     kubernetes.io/os=linux
>                     node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker
>                     node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=k3s
>                     plan.upgrade.cattle.io/agent-plan=0e4e3f4e3f8b1e811d841099cb49e4712b93833bee060___________
> Annotations:        flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VNI":1,"VtepMAC":"42:f7:a9:29:4e:ee"}
>                     flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
>                     flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
>                     flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 192.168.1.240
>                     k3s.io/hostname: homelab02
>                     k3s.io/internal-ip: 192.168.1.240
>                     k3s.io/node-args: ["agent"]
>                     k3s.io/node-config-hash: ____________________________YXZJNIEGESVCQKJGAVTCZIEA====
>                     k3s.io/node-env:
>                       {"K3S_DATA_DIR":"/var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/3dfc950bd39d2e2b435291ab8c133___________________________________","K3S_TOKEN":"********","K3S_U...
>                     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
>                     volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
> CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 29 Dec 2022 22:24:28 +0100
> Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
> Unschedulable:      false
> Lease:
>   HolderIdentity:  homelab02
>   AcquireTime:     <unset>
>   RenewTime:       Wed, 13 Mar 2024 16:43:18 +0100
> Conditions:
>   Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
>   ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
>   MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 13 Mar 2024 16:38:39 +0100   Tue, 09 Jan 2024 09:00:08 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
>   DiskPressure     True    Wed, 13 Mar 2024 16:38:39 +0100   Mon, 11 Mar 2024 07:41:34 +0100   KubeletHasDiskPressure       kubelet has disk pressure
>   PIDPressure      False   Wed, 13 Mar 2024 16:38:39 +0100   Tue, 09 Jan 2024 09:00:08 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
>   Ready            True    Wed, 13 Mar 2024 16:38:39 +0100   Tue, 09 Jan 2024 09:00:08 +0100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
> Addresses:
>   InternalIP:  192.168.1.240
>   Hostname:    homelab02
> Capacity:
>   cpu:                2
>   ephemeral-storage:  3841415456Ki
>   hugepages-1Gi:      0
>   hugepages-2Mi:      0
>   memory:             8002768Ki
>   pods:               110
> Allocatable:
>   cpu:                2
>   ephemeral-storage:  3736928952667
>   hugepages-1Gi:      0
>   hugepages-2Mi:      0
>   memory:             8002768Ki
>   pods:               110
> System Info:
>   Machine ID:                 f289b111cbe53747cf8d9976542fdd64
>   System UUID:                17ad5d80-1dd2-11b2-8000-9cb654092d10
>   Boot ID:                    8d3831b4-c4c7-4a65-bcd1-22fbe4c65362
>   Kernel Version:             6.1.0-17-amd64
>   OS Image:                   Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
>   Operating System:           linux
>   Architecture:               amd64
>   Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.7.6-k3s1.27
>   Kubelet Version:            v1.27.6+k3s1
>   Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.27.6+k3s1
> PodCIDR:                      10.42.1.0/24
> PodCIDRs:                     10.42.1.0/24
> ProviderID:                   k3s://homelab02
> Non-terminated Pods:          (3 in total)
>   Namespace                   Name                                      CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
>   ---------                   ----                                      ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
>   kube-system                 coredns-77ccd57875-zjgh4                  100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     173d
>   kube-system                 local-path-provisioner-957fdf8bc-tktsx    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         173d
>   kube-system                 metrics-server-648b5df564-rpndv           100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        0 (0%)         173d
> Allocated resources:
>   (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
>   Resource           Requests    Limits
>   --------           --------    ------
>   cpu                200m (10%)  0 (0%)
>   memory             140Mi (1%)  170Mi (2%)
>   ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
>   hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
>   hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
> Events:
>   Type     Reason                Age                      From     Message
>   ----     ------                ----                     ----     -------
>   Warning  EvictionThresholdMet  5m1s (x20383 over 2d9h)  kubelet  Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
> ```

## Update 2

I freed up 200GB:
`df -h` output:

> ```
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
> tmpfs           782M  3.6M  778M   1% /run
> /dev/md0        3.6T  3.1T  339G  91% /
> tmpfs           3.9G  1.2M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
> tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
> tmpfs           782M  8.0K  782M   1% /run/user/1000
> ```

... but still I get the same issues listed:

`kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TAINTS:.spec.taints --no-headers`:

> ```
> homelab02      [map[effect:NoSchedule key:node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure timeAdded:2024-03-13T20:08:04Z]]
> himinbjorg   <none>
> ```

`kubectl taint nodes homelab02 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure-`:

> ```
> node/homelab02 untainted
> ```

`kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TAINTS:.spec.taints --no-headers`:

> ```
> himinbjorg   <none>
> homelab02      [map[effect:NoSchedule key:node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure timeAdded:2024-03-13T22:14:04Z]]
> ```

`kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=homelab02`:

> ```
> LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                 OBJECT         MESSAGE
> 18m         Warning   EvictionThresholdMet   node/homelab02   Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
> 3m          Warning   FreeDiskSpaceFailed    node/homelab02   (combined from similar events): Failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Attempted to free 423227714764 bytes, but only found 0 bytes eligible to free.
> ```

Comment: Review Kubernetes Events: Use `kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=homelab02` check node logs of node homelab02 Identify Resource-Hungry Pods: Use `kubectl describe node homelab02` Review Storage Classes and Persistent Volumes: If your pods are using persistent volumes, make sure that the underlying storage is properly provisioned and that there are no issues with storage classes or volume claims.

Comment: Check the hard eviction threshold section of the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#hard-eviction-thresholds

If you did not personalize the thresholds, the disk being 91% will trigger hard eviction and node pressure. You could configure the threshold to a lower value, but probably it would be better to free more space on the disk.